# 42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I dont use: EnsureCreated anywhere.
When I update the database from the migration. I get:

```
  [17:10:43 ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (96ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
    "Id" text NOT NULL,
    "Name" character varying(256) NULL,
    "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
```

The problem is in postresql, I have never encountered it in SQL database.

How can I prevent that error from happening?

Comment: Does the table `AspNetRoles` already exist in your database? In case it does and you do not need it, consider `DROP TABLE AspNetRoles;` ;)

Comment: no. thats not the problem. I cant drop a table in production.